# How to pause css animation at orginal state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm using this animation for ajax loader: http://codepen.io/hericdk/pen/niweF
Now when ajax call is finished I'd like animated gif to change to "check mark" then i want animation to pause and then slowly fade out so i do :

```
$('.spinner').css("background-image", "url('/img/complete.png')");
$('.spinner').addClass("animationpaused");
$('.spinner').fadeOut(800);
```

where animationpaused css is :

```
.animationpaused{
  -webkit-animation-play-state:paused !important;
  -moz-animation-play-state:paused !important;
  -o-animation-play-state:paused !important;
  animation-play-state:paused !important;
}
```

Problem is sometimes I can get "check mark" icon to pause upside down.
How can I pause CSS animation and be sure it pauses in original state so my icon will never pause upside-down?

Edit:
I've added fiddle to make this more clear:
http://jsfiddle.net/oL31LwdL/1/ Basicly after clicking stop button I'd like animation to continue to 1st frame and then stop so check icon will be in its original position.

Comment: Pause will pause the animation immediately, setting `animation-name` to `none` will make it snap back to the original position immediately. It won't smoothly go back to original state. As far as I know there is no way to gracefully transition/animate it back to original position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add animation-fill-mode. In your case you probably need:

```
animation-fill-mode: none;
```

Find more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: I've added animation-fill-mode: none;  but nothing changes
I still do something wrong - see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oL31LwdL/1/
Basicly after clicking stop button I'd like animation to continue to 1st frame and then stop so check icon will be in its original position.

Comment: In your case, you need to use this line ALSO: animation-name: none; together with animation-fill-mode: none; Take a look on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oL31LwdL/2/

Comment: @DejanMunjiza: As I just indicated in my comment to the question, setting `animation-name: none` will not gracefully move it back to original state, it will snap back immediately. This would be more obvious when `animation-duration` is higher. I know OP has accepted the answer but leaving the comment for information purposes.

Comment: Now it works as I'd like it to - thanks. Smooth animation to starting position would look better I guess but I'll do fine for my purposes.